# didDisconnectPeripheral: not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have a custom object `BLEDevice` which has a weak reference to a `CBPeripheral` object. I maintain a dictionary that keeps the associations between the peripherals and my custom objects:

```
- (void)setDeviceForPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    // New device: sets a new 'BLEDevice' instance
    BLEDevice *new = [[BLEDevice alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheral];
    new.name = peripheral.name;
    new.peripheral.delegate = self;
    [associations setObject:new forKey:peripheral];
}
```

When I discover a new peripheral in the nearbies, I perform the following operations:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    if (![associations objectForKey:peripheral]) {
        NSLog(@"Found peripheral: %@", peripheral.name);
        [self setDeviceForPeripheral:peripheral];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BLEDeviceFound" object:nil];
    }
}
```

At this point, I define a custom method to connect to my device:

```
- (void)connect:(BLEDevice *)device {
    // Connects with the peripheral
    [manager connectPeripheral:device.peripheral options:nil];
}
```

Here everything works just fine: my peripheral gets connected and I start performing operations on services and characteristics inside the delegate method `centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:`.

Now my troubles come. When I want to disconnect to my peripheral, I perform the following operations:

```
- (void)disconnect:(BLEDevice *)device {
    // Unsubscribes from all the characteristics in services
    for (CBService *service in device.peripheral.services) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
            [device.peripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
    [manager cancelPeripheralConnection:device.peripheral];
}
```

When I call this method, my peripheral device confirms me that the disconnection was successful. Anyway, the delegate method `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:` is not getting called. Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: You are disconnect and expect the disconnect delegate method to be called????? Am I right?

Comment: @JasonNam Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: hey Dree, didDisconnectPeripheral was called when your CBPeripheral state change to state = disconnected, you can debug this.... First of all check that your manager is exist(should use singletone), and check your CBCentralManagerState too..... CentralManager should know about all CBPeripherals and about their states, check your code maybe you killed CentralManager somethere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is not called when you disconnect the peripherals as the name of it tells. What you want is the following.

```
- centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:
```

The document says:

> Invoked when an existing connection with a peripheral is torn down.

The delegate method will be called when you disconnect the peripherals.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. That was my fault. I call the right method inside my code, I just mistype it here. I edit the question.

Comment: Have you ever checked that if the method is called when you remove the weak symbol???

Comment: The `disconnect` method is always called and my device correctly disconnects from the smartphone. But the delegate method is never called.  Removing the weak reference doesn't change anything.

Comment: Check if there are any typos!

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that the solution is really simple. I just called the wrong delegate method. The correct signature is

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error.
```

This shit has been driving me crazy since weeks!

Comment: ahahah! Are you sarcastic? :P

Comment: I am glad that you solved with your problem, coreblueTooth is realy difficult.

Comment: Thank you! :) Have a nice day Joe!